# DoubleType to VectorUDT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have this code written using Spark 2.1:

```
val mycolumns = originalFile.schema.fieldNames
mycolumns.map(cname => stddevPerColumnName(df.select(cname), cname))


def stddevPerColumnName(df: DataFrame, cname: String): DataFrame =
  new StandardScaler()
      .setInputCol(cname)
      .setOutputCol("stddev")
      .setWithStd(true)
      .fit(df)
      .transform(df)
```

Every single column has type DoubleType originally inferred from a CSV file.
When I run the code I get the Exception:

```
Column FirstColumn must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 but was actually DoubleType.
```

How can I convert the column type `Double` to `VectorUDT`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass vector into `ML model:`use `assembler` to put `double values` into `vector` then do your `ML` then take values out of `vector` if required back to `double`

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{MinMaxScaler,VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("yourDoubleValue")).setOutputCol("features")
def assembler (ds: Dataset[T]) = {mlib.assembler.transform(ds)}
val vectorToColumn = udf{ (x: DenseVector, index: Int) => x(index) }
val scaler = new StandardScaler().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("featuresScaled")
```

*use `DenseVector` or `SparseVector` depending on your data

full example:

`val data = spark.read....`

```
val data_assembled = assembler.transform(data)

val assembled = scaler.fit(ds).transform(ds)
  .withColumn("backToMyDouble",round(mlib.vectorToColumn(col("featuresScaled"),lit(0)),2))
```